# Verificar Checkbox Dinamico (Checado) vindos de um while dentro do banco de dados

Tags: php, mysql, checkbox, while

Boa noite Pessoal, estou batendo a cabeça aqui com isso...
Tenho duas tabelas no banco, uma corresponde a o departamento e outra corresponde aos checkbox cadastrados para esse departamento, o problema é, como trazer esses checkbox marcados, por exemplo, preciso validar eles na exibição, como "checked", isso dentro do while, mas são duas tabelas diferentes... eu até consegui chegar em metade do caminho, porém ele exibe somente um resultado.
Seguem abaixo tabela e código, se alguém puder dar uma ajuda, agradeço muito.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM departamentos";
$rs = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
while($departamento = mysqli_fetch_array($rs)){
                                    
$sql2 = "SELECT DISTINCT id_departamento FROM checkbox WHERE tipo='1' AND id_galeria_artigo='$id'";
$rs2 = mysqli_query($conn, $sql2);
$checkbox = mysqli_fetch_array($rs2)
?>
<label class="btn <?php if($departamento['id'] == $checkbox['id_departamento']) { echo 'active';}?>"  style="margin:5px">
     <input type="checkbox" name="check[]" value="<?php echo $departamento['id']?>" > <?php echo $departamento['title']?>
</label>
<?php
    }
?>
```

Essta é a tabela "checkbox":

[image: ,]

Tabela Departamento:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Tabela Galeria:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: pode postar a outra tabela? e o resultado esperado?

Comment: O segundo SELECT retorna sempre o mesmo resultado dentro do while

Comment: Então Leo, a outra tabela seria somente o departamento, no caso, o cliente cadastra uma galeria, e essa galeria precisa aparecer nos respectivos departamentos selecionados, esses departamentos são selecionados via checkbox, e salvam na tabela "checkbox", quando o usuario vai editar essa galeria no painel, preciso exibir os checkbox para os respectivos departamentos, e preciso verificar se esse checkbox foi selecionado ou não, para marcar como checado, entende?

Comment: Entendo, mas sem essa tabela não posso rodar o script para realizar testes.

Comment: Entendi... upei as duas tabelas, a do departamento, e a da galeria, galeria acredito não ser tão relevante, pois só pega o id da galeria selecionada...

Comment: rodei aqui e retornou isso https://i.stack.imgur.com/BnTfV.png

Comment: é por conta do "check" no input, editei ali em cima e tirei ele, o que faz a validação de ativo ou não é o if em cima, se esse departamento estiver ativo, ele imprime o "active"

Comment: esse $id vem de onde?

Comment: ele pega da galeria, dentro dessa galeria eu tenho os departamentos para serem selecionados.

Comment: Não estou enxergando qual seria o problema, a imagem que te mostrei não é o resultado esperado? Qual seria o resultado esperado?